# Need one block on Regex to be optional

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex - "\^CV_(\w+)?-(\w+)?-Base"

```
var matches = new Regex(@"\^CV_(\w+)?-(\w+)?-Base").Matches("EnglUS^CV_Common-Concierge-Base^0^0^0");
var matchGroups = matches[0].Groups;
var parentCatMatch = matchGroups[1].Value;
var childCatMatch = matchGroups[2].Value;
```

I get proper regex matches and groups for the above value but I get exception for the below one -

```
**Exception:** Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: i 

var matches = new Regex(@"\^CV_(\w+)?-(\w+)?-Base").Matches("EnglUS^CV_Common-Base^0^0^0");
var matchGroups = matches[0].Groups;
var parentCatMatch = matchGroups[1].Value;
var childCatMatch = matchGroups[2].Value;
```

Question: What should I change in the regex that the second word block - "`Concierge`" becomes optional from this word - "`EnglUS^CV_Common-Concierge-Base^0^0^0`"

I searched online for this but didn't got it working, my some changes in the regex even stopped the total match at all, so I am posting here if someone of greater expertise with regex could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\^CV_((\w+)-){1,2}Base
```

this makes sure that each group after the CV_ is in the form of (\w) followed by (-). and {1,2} is telling the expression it requires minimum of 1 and maximum of 2.

Comment: hi, this appears to be working but just one very small issue i.e. the matchGroups[1].Value; returns "Common-" means a hiphen is appended, however I removed it using c# .remove(), but if regex can remove it then this would be perfect, can you help?

Comment: if you go to matchGroups[2].Captures, you will see that "Common" and "Concierge" are listed there. matchGroups[n].Captures is a collection of strings.

Answer (score 3):

```
\^CV_(\w+)?(?:-(\w+))?-Base

             ^^
```

Just put the `-` inside `optional group`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/27

Comment: sorry it isn't working in c#, same error, making this change doesn't gets anything in groups.

Comment: hi, I tried this as well but matches[0].Groups; returns no match in c#, I saw your edit in the answer and I tried this immediately, sorry friend

Comment: ok, you mean this link has different regex, let me try it, thanks

Comment: I tried the new regex and it returns the groups, but the other answer solves more of my purpose. Won't be able to explain much but this string contains parent and child categories, and an XML is generated, in the other answer parent category word is repeated for child category as well, which is solving my purpose that it matches the regex even when child category is not present, In brief - you both are correct according to the question is have posted, just the other one is solving my issue bit more correctly. Thanks for your answer :)